# Is there a way to include heading in link from org-outlook

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

'New to OrgMode'

I am using org-outlook to capture email from outlook as task. I have a file ToDo.org with different multi-level headings. Looking for a way to put task under a specific heading.

Right now I am using file+function in capture template:

```
("u" "mycv" entry (file+function "~/Private/OrgMode/ToDo.org"
                 (lambda () (let ((org-goto-interface 'outline-path-completion))
                                    (org-goto))))
```

This gives me an option to select heading/sub-heading from file but but I want to automate this step as well, if I can read Heading info from the link coming from outlook. I can customize VBA to include any info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the filename and the sequence of headlines under which you want to capture the new item, then you just need a `file+olp` target as described in the doc string of `org-capture-templates`. The entry would look like this:

```el
("u" "mycv" entry (file+olp "~/Private/OrgMode/ToDo.org" "Level 1 Headline" "Level 2 Headline" ...) <some template>)
```

If the headline under which you want the new item is unique in the file, you can get away with a simpler target: `(file+headline <file> <headline>)`, but the full-path specification of `file+olp` is safer in the long term.

See the doc string of `org-capture-templates` with `C-h v org-capture-templates`:

> ```
>    ...
>    (file+headline "path/to/file" "node headline")
>         Fast configuration if the target heading is unique in the file
>
>     (file+olp "path/to/file" "Level 1 heading" "Level 2" ...)
>         For non-unique headings, the full outline path is safer
>     ...
> ```

*EDIT*: if you want the outline path to be dynamically constructed, then you'll have to construct the `org-capture-templates` entry at runtime, and let-bind `org-capture-templates` around a call to `org-capture` in a function of your own. Since you don't provide an interface, I'm going to make some assumptions and write a function based on those assumptions, but I hope what you have to do will be clear enough so that you can tweak the function to your requirements.

The basic assumption is that somebody constructs a list of headlines under which the new item is to be inserted. The list is sorted by headline level, so that if you want the new entry to go into a file `my.org` under the following headlines:

```
* foo
** bar
*** baz
<new item goes here>
```

the required list will be `("foo" "bar" "baz")` in that order.

Based on that assumption, you can write a function that takes the path of the file, an olp list  and the text of your new entry as arguments and does what it needs to have the new entry inserted in the specified place:

```el
(defun my/insert-item-in-olp-hierarchy (path olp entry)
  (let ((org-capture-templates
         `(("u" "mycv" entry
            (file+olp ,path ,@olp)
            ,(format "* This is my new entry: %s" entry)
            :immediate-finish t))))
    (org-capture nil "u")))
```

You call it with something like this: `(my/insert-item-in-olp-hierarchy "~/org/foo.org" '("foo" "bar" "baz") "My new entry")`

The first level `foo` heading, second level `bar` heading and third level `baz` heading *MUST* already exist in the file or else you'll get an error. The new entry is inserted at the fourth level as specified by the template in the let-bound `org-capture-templates`. The function uses the `backquote` mechanism (read about it in the elisp manual: `C-h i g(elisp)Backquote`) to substitute in the path of the file and splice in the outline path list, as the `file+olp` entry type expects. And we specify `:immediate-finish t`, so that the new entry is entered directly in the file, without popping up a buffer to edit it before submitting it, since it's supposed to be self contained. For these details, careful study of the `org-capture-templates` doc string is warranted: see above for how to get the doc string.

This is just an example and you'll have to adapt it to your circumstances, but I think it contains all of the important elements you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply but headline hierarchy is not constant. Its dynamic and  defined as part of link I am sending from Outlook.

Comment: Then you'll have to write a function that constructs the entry dynamically, let-binds `org-capture-templates` so that it contains the new entry and then calls `org-capture` with the `u` argument so that the entry is used in the capture. I'll update the answer with an indication of how that would go.

Comment: Thanks NickD. I'll wait for it...

Comment: Example of dynamic capture added.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was thinking that this code will overwrite org-capture-templates variable and I'll lose all other templates but looks like its working fine and I still have my templates from init.el . (though I have no idea why its not overwriting org-capture-templates defined in init.el, maybe some scoping in lisp)

Comment: The `let` does a local binding which is only active during the function invocation. Afterwards, the let-binding is no longer active so `org-capture-templates` is bound to whatever it was bound before. See the description of `let` in the Elisp manual with `C-h i g(elisp)Local variables`.